# MySQL service doesn't start

Tags: centos, mysql

I have a CentOS 6.6, on the system there was a working Mysql and a mysql server already installed and a running mysqld service, but I needed a fresh install, so I did the whole removal through yum, and removal of the old Mysql residue files (double checked for remaining files).

Installation:

```
[root@sputnik mysql]# yum install mysql mysql-server
```

Installation completes successfully without errors.

Starting Mysql service on a few different ways:

```
[root@sputnik mysql]# service mysqld start
 
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

[root@sputnik mysql]# mysql

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

    [root@sputnik mysql]# mysqld_safe
    
    150127 11:44:39 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/sputnik.fadata.eu.err'.
    150127 11:44:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
    150127 11:44:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/sputnik.fadata.eu.pid ended
```

**/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock** this file doesn't exist anywhere in the system, and through research I found that it is generated during mysqld service starting but the service refuses to start because it is missing?

**/var/lib/mysql/sputnik.fadata.eu** log file contains:

```
150127 11:36:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150127 11:36:07 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
150127 11:36:07 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150127 11:36:07  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150127 11:36:07  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150127 11:36:07  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
150127 11:36:07 [ERROR] Aborting
```

**/var/log/mysqld.log** contains nothing,
**/var/run/mysqld** is an empty directory

Already checked/tried:

- I have tried mysql secure installationand complete reinstallation a few times,
- Tried to manually insert an errmsg.sys file,
- Tried to install initial tables and databases manually.
  The Mysql user **exists** and it is the owner and has the necessary privileges over it's files,
- Tried to start mysql service and mysqld service through init.d and all other ways, **no** service containing mysql or mysqld is running.

Basically I tried everything I found on the forums, so the problem is I need to install and set mysql service to run. These are the details and errors I have. If I need to post more details please let me know.

Comment: Ahaha! I found out how to reinstall mysql-community-server, as you writing it here. I found a good description at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html in the chapter 2:
...you can also select a release series by editing manually the /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo file. This is a typical entry for a release series' subrepository in the file: # Enable to use MySQL 5.6 [mysql56-community] name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/5/$basearch/ enabled=1 gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it...

If someone gets in a similar situation where no mysql-server install doesn't go through, after making sure that the installation steps were correct but service won't start or create necessary files see the following:

**Problem was:** 
I looked at my repos, fault was there, i had corrupted repos that led to downloading and installing wrong mysql-server version or something.

**Solution:**
Remove Mysql completely and all files, Find your correct repo rpm package on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/ download the correct version and install the rpm package through `yum localinstall`, 
verify if the correct repo is enabled :

```
# yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
```

**Only one version is allowed to be enabled at a time !**

Then install mysql-server again through yum

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

Run the service mysqld again and it will create all the necessary files and tables without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to update packages.

Todo on **fresh** centos installation (mysql is not installed yet):

```
yum check-update
yum update
yum install mysql mysql-server
```